# How to transform integer to string with certain character length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataset (integer value)

```
d
6
17
345
```

Here's what I want (string value)

```
d
0006
0017
0345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with Python format function in this case:

```
df['d'].apply('{:04d}'.format)
# or
# df['d'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:04d}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str.zfill` to prepending "0"s:

```
df['d'] = df['d'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

Output:

```
      d
0  0006
1  0017
2  0345
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
df['d'].astype(str).str.pad(width=4, side='left', fillchar='0')
Out[226]: 
0    0006
1    0017
2    0345
Name: d, dtype: object
```